# Drag multi item to the same text box

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, expression

Im using the following code to drag from list box to text box ,
when I have one text box and I use the following code it prevent to drag item to text box that already filled with Item

```
 private void listbox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if ((e.AddedItems.Count == 1) &&
                (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox1.Text) ))
```

but when I add new text box (textbox2) and  try to check if it already filled ,the check is failed
for all of the text boxes ,how can I avoid that?

```
     private void listbox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if ((e.AddedItems.Count == 1) &&
                (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox1.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox2.Text)))
            {
....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend to use Drag/Drop events for textboxes, like:

```
private void textBox1_DragEnter(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs e)
```

and inside method handler check if drop is allowed.  That works more logically.

Check complete article here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984430%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: when I put the code of drag enter on the xaml and on the main window ,the debugger doesn't stop when I drag item to the text box,any idea?

Comment: private void DropList_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!e.Data.GetDataPresent("myFormat") ||
                sender == e.Source)
            {
                e.Effects = DragDropEffects.None;
            }
        }

Comment: in the xaml -  <TextBox x:Name="textbox1"  
                  AcceptsReturn="True"
                  AllowDrop="True" 
                  DragOver="textbox_DragOver"
                  PreviewDrop="textbox1_PreviewDrop"  
                  Grid.Column="1"
                 DragEnter="DropList_DragEnter"

Comment: @JohnJerrby do you do:
DragDrop.DoDragDrop(...) when drag starts on listview?

Comment: for WPF check this examples - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742859%28v=vs.110%29.aspx